# Using multiconfig to build and include a coprocessor firmware in linux machine build

Tags: linux, yocto

We have this custom Linux system that is being built on Yocto, which has a Nordic co-processor, running a custom Zephyr RTOS system.

I know Yocto can now build Zephyr machines, but is it possible to build the Zephyr binary, and include it in a Linux Yocto build as firmware binary (the update of the coprocessor is out of scope of this question) in a single recipe (like building an update package that builds multiple images, one of which is for a different MACHINE)?

Searching for this on Google is hard, since all the keywords pertaining to this problem also refer generally to using Yocto itself...